# why is my string no string anymore after give it to a function?

Tags: javascript, html, string, href

SOLVED: read edit below

First of all i create a string like this:

```
var child_id = "childId"+this.id;
alert(child_id);
```

the alert shows the correct string. this.id is a string and i also made a temp variable and put it again into a string (var tmp_child_id = child_id.toString()) to get sure it is a string.

after this i give this string to the function goToNextNode with a href link like this:

```
this.svgImageDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:goToNextNode('+child_id+')"><img src="img/transparent.png"/></a>
```

in the function goToNextNode i fire an alert at first and it dont show the string like the alert above, it says "[Object HTMLDivElement]".

```
function goToNextNode(childId){
   alert(childId);
}
```

What happend to my string and how do i transport the string correctly?

EDIT:
SOLVED:
when i do  var child_id = this.id; instead of  var child_id = "childId"+this.id; and put the "childId" string to the id in the function goToNextNode() everything works. Dont ask me why it does behave like this, i dont get it...

END EDIT

Comment: What exactly are you alerting? And is this.id a string as well?

Comment: Can you show your goToNextNode()?

Comment: @remyabel, yes it is, i also put it again into a string with a tmp variable like i show above, i edited my post and also put the goToNextNode function into my post

Comment: @DD59 when i write alert(child_id) i alert the var child_id and not the childid i give to the function... the value of the child_id variable changes pretty fast, thats why i put the value into the href link.

Comment: try `console.log(childId)` check the value in the console of your browser

Comment: i solved it, check the edit above. but i dont know why it is solved... :D

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes for the argument inside the brackets:

```
this.svgImageDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:goToNextNode(`'+child_id+'`)"><img src="img/transparent.png"/></a>';
```

Comment: hmm but it dont works like you wrote and if i wrote it like this it doesnt work because it closes the javascript quote from the beginning: `this.svgImageDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:goToNextNode('+'"'+child_id+'"'+')"><img src="img/transparent.png"/></a>';`

Comment: The first '"' you add inside the brackets will be the end of the value for the href-attribute. You could use escaped high commas: `this.svgImageDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:goToNextNode(\''+child_id+'\')"><img src="img/transparent.png"/></a>';`